# How do I prevent infinite loop when isAuthenticated is undefined in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm getting an infinite render loop because the value of `isSignedIn` is initially undefined. How do I solve this?

**Container.jsx**

```
class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchUserInit();
  }

  render() {
    const { path } = this.props.match;
    const isSignedIn = this.props.sessionData.signed_in;
    return (
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRouteWrapper scope='employers'>
          <Route exact path={path}>
            <div>
              <HeaderContainer />
              <WelcomeContainer />
            </div>
          </Route>
        </ProtectedRouteWrapper>

        <Route path={`${path}/dashboard`}>
          <HeaderContainer />
          <EmployerDashboardContainer />
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  sessionData: state.session.userData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onFetchUserInit: () => dispatch(fetchUserInit()),

});
```

**ProtectedRouteWrapper.jsx**

```
const ProtectedRouteWrapper = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const isSignedIn = useSelector(state => state.session.userData.signed_in)

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
          isSignedIn === true ? ( children ) : <LoginContainer />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: What flow do you believe is causing the re-render (ie not signed in > sign in updates redux > etc)? Is there a reason you are combining the old react coding with new react-hook coding? Some parts of your code are missing. Can you post a sample onto codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route to *LoginContainer* component and redirect user to it in *ProtectedRouteWrapper*.

```js
class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchUserInit();
  }

  render() {
    const { path } = this.props.match;
    const isSignedIn = this.props.sessionData.signed_in;
    return (
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRouteWrapper scope='employers'>
          <Route exact path={path}>
            <div>
              <HeaderContainer />
              <WelcomeContainer />
            </div>
          </Route>
        </ProtectedRouteWrapper>

        <Route path={`${path}/dashboard`}>
          <HeaderContainer />
          <EmployerDashboardContainer />
        </Route>

        <Route path={`/login`}>
          <LoginContainer />
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  sessionData: state.session.userData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onFetchUserInit: () => dispatch(fetchUserInit()),

});
```

Adding reload:

```js
const ProtectedRouteWrapper = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const isSignedIn = useSelector(state => state.session.userData.signed_in)

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
          isSignedIn === true ? ( children ) :
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      }
    />
  );
}
```